# what is the import for CallableContext

Tags: typescript, google-cloud-functions

I have simple [google cloud function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable) as follows

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
var util = require('util')

export const repeat = functions.https.onCall( 
    function (data, context) {
        console.log(' repeat1 '+ util.inspect(data) + util.inspect(context) );
        return { fld1: 'xyz', fld2: 10};
    }
);
```

I want to separate the function o I am trying as follows

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
var util = require('util')

export const repeat = functions.https.onCall( 
    xyzFunction
);

function xyzFunction(data: any, context: CallableContext) 
{ 
    console.log(' repeat1 '+ util.inspect(data) + util.inspect(context) );
        return { fld1: 'xyz', fld2: 10};
}
```

but I get error ,I can solve it by using any, but https.d.ts declare it as CallableContext, so I want to keep same type. I am coming from java background. So what import should I use ?

> TS2304: Cannot find name 'CallableContext'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The CallableContext type is exported via `functions.https`:

```
function xyzFunction(data: any, context: functions.https.CallableContext) {
    ...
}
```